# Add Data From Text File Using Parallel Programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am trying to read data from a .txt file, store them into a List, and then using parallel programming to do this twice at the same time. I have 2 .txt files containing a bunch of numbers to add up. I declare both files, then store them into List objects.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file1 = @"filepath.txt";
    var file2 = @"filepath.txt";
    List<string> List = File.ReadAllLines(file1).ToList();
    List<string> List2 = File.ReadAllLines(file2).ToList();

    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < List.Count i++)
    {
        num += Convert.ToInt16(List[i].ToString());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < List2.Count; i++)
    {
        num2 += Convert.ToInt16(List2[i].ToString());
    }
    listBox1.Items.Add(num);
    listBox2.Items.AddNum
}
```

As for the for the @"filepath.txt", they are both exact paths, just didn't want to have 2 long lines of file location.
This is what I need to do, but do it using multi-threading, parallel programming, or asynchronous programming.

Comment: I suggest you go and look up some task examples, or plinq, or AsParallel, or even take a tour through the TPL documentation

Comment: @TheGeneral I have researched it, I haven't found anything yet. I wouldn't post this if I hadn't already looked it up or at least have tried to do it myself. I've seen posts on here asking how to parse data, which is more simple than this. I also don't do much coding in C# and it's one if my least favorite languages, but I gotta bite the bullet and learn it. Don't know why you came off so aggressive to a simple question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it came off as aggressive, as this honestly wasn't the intent. however its a very low quality question with little benefit to future readers, as all this information is already found on stack overflow and internet. i suggest looking into tasks, and the TPL (Task Parallel library) and see how you go

Comment: @TheGeneral Okay, thank you for your help. Sorry for it being such a simple question though. Spent some time looking it up and I just can't find out the solution. Will check out TPL right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after asynchronous process that prevent your form from locking in form load event, you can do something like this.

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      //Your code here
    },  CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If you want to include parallelism in your program, you can do something like this.

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
        options.TaskScheduler = taskScheduler;
        Parallel.Invoke(options,
            () =>
            {
                //Update your listBox1
            },
            () =>
            {
                //Update your listBox2
            }
            );
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
}
```